# XCode 9: UI API called from background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, arkit

Не запускается простейшее ARKit приложение. Просто исходная демо сцена из ARKit для Unity.
 - Экспортирую для Ios, устанавливаю через XCode 9, все ок.
 - Запускаю: на экране iPhone висит "Waiting for editor connection..." а в Xcode куча предупреждений и одна ошибка:  "UI API called from background thread", "UIApplication delegate must be used from main thread only".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я новичок, еще не работаю в Objective-C, но судя по урокам вроде [этого](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7kKQZuOdlk&t=4s) так быть не должно.

В чем может быть дело и как это исправить?
Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UI API called from background thread

Это предупреждение говорит о том, что вы обращаетесь к элементам пользовательского интерфейса, которые принадлежат потоку main, из другого потока, а этого делать нельзя.

В вашем случае поток Thread 5 (*обратите внимание на стек вызовов слева и название потока*) не владеет пользовательским интерфейсом, а метод `GetAppController` вызываемый из `UnityCurrentOrientation` обращается к UI и вы получаете предупреждение.

Если вам нужно обращаться к пользовательскому интерфейсу из других потоков, то вам нужно выполнить такой код в main-потоке, например:

используя [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue)

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // Обращение к UI
}];
```

или [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch?language=objc):

```
dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^{
    // Обращение к UI
});
```